# jQuery delay issue

Tags: jquery, submit, toggle, delay, fade

I have an issue with my jQuery code.  There is a popup panel that I have in my site that contains a form.  When I click Submit on my form, my data is submitted to my email and database (as requested).  However, once this has been submitted, I want:

1. My form `<div>` to hide.
2. My confirmation `<div>` to show.
3. A 2 second delay to take place.
4. My entire form panel to fade out.
5. My confirmation `<div>` and my form `<div>` to restore to normal (including resetting the form, which I am not sure how to do, so any help on that front would also be grateful)

Note: I want 5. to take place so that a second email can be sent if needed.  I can live without that, but at least up to 4. would be needed.

When I submit my form, my data is processed as desired, but my panel is hidden as a whole, with no `<div>` transitions taking place, so I do not see my confirmation message.  My code is currently set as:

```
$.post('/includes/hireme.php', $("#formHireMe").serialize(), function(data) {
  $('div#hiremeFormPane').hide();
  $('div#hiremeSubmittedPane').show().delay(5000).hide();
  $('div#hiremeFormPane').show();
  $('div#hiremePanel').fadeOut(150);
});
```

Does anyone know a) why? or b) if there is a better way of achieving that effect?

Comment: I should note that, before I added the `.delay`, my confirmation message did show.  Everything after the delay was an afterthought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show` and `hide` are not animations when they are not given a duration.  `delay` affects the animation queue.  Since `show` and `hide` are not being place on the animation queue, `delay` is not delaying the `hide`, causing it to immediately hide.

You can either give `hide` a duration (even 1 will do making it nearly instant, but placing it on the animation queue to now be affected by `delay`) or you will need to use `setTimeout` or some other animation like `fadeOut`.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware that there had to be durations (I am a noob, I know, I will learn), but I have it working now.  Thank you.